# Git: branch is not added in GitHub

Tags: git, unix, github

I'm making new branch in terminal on MacOS. I typed `$ git branch backend` and branch was created. Than i typed `$ git checkout backend` so I was in that branch.

Now I typed `$ git push -u origin backend` and branch is still not on **GitHub.com**.

I'm sorry for that banal error but I'm lost.

Comment: What was the actual error, if there were one?

Comment: I had no error but I think I forgot some commands right?

Comment: I'm not sure, But just a test. Make a new branch except for the name `backend`. Then try to `checkout` and `push` again.

Comment: `git status`? `git branch -vv`? `git diff @{u}..backend`?

Comment: Please check if you are pointing to correct remote URL: git remote -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the same push, but after having done at least one commit, for testing:

```sh
     git checkout backend 
     # change e file content
     git add .
     git commit -m "new commit in backend branch"
     git push -u origin backend
```

Make sure your branch does start from master, with

```sh
    git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches
```